# Is there a good outliner/note-taking alternative to emacs org-mode (with images)?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, todo, outliner

Org-mode from Emacs is awesome to scribble down project notes and also maintain a todo list where you can quickly move things around (up/down, indentation etc.). However, especially when it comes to images, the emacs is rather limited (since it's a text-editor). There are ways to include images, even copy-pasted images from the clipboard, but the results are rather unsatisfactory. For instance, an image in emacs is treated as a character, so if the images is higher than your screen there is no way to see the bottom of it. The existing workarounds for the scrolling problems are also not very satisfactory.

Is there any good alternative to emacs org-mode? I checked through dozens of programs, but no other software (that supports rich-text) would allow for fast, keyboard-based folding and moving of items.

Comment: Include the image as org-mode would do and then convert into HTML with org-export and view it.

Comment: OmniOutliner is good for this, but is Mac-only and some would consider it expensive.

Comment: @aartist: That's hardly an option, I need to really work within the document, not export it later on. It's essentially a combination of my to-do list and my project notes (some of which are images).

Comment: @Kristopher: Yea, I came around this piece of software. That company develops incredibly cool software, also OmniGraffle, but only for Mac OS :-\. I am on Win7 64.

Answer (score 6):

Org-mode has now in development (git) the following, that would fit images in Org buffers, with no need for thumbnails, etc.:

(setq org-image-actual-width 300)

=> always resize inline images to 300 pixels

etc...

Development version:
http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/
git://orgmode.org/org-mode.git

Comment: Thanks juan for the response. I'd like to try that, but I am on Win7, using an EmacsW32 variant. Specifically, this is behind that port:

GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)
 of 2009-11-04 on LENNART-69DE564 (patched).

Will I be able to use a nightly version into this Windows editor framework?

Comment: In http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org.el#n17031 they say: _"This requires Emacs >= 24.1, build with imagemagick support."_ Like Emacs, ImageMagick is also open-source and cross-platform, including MS Windows.

Comment: `GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601) of 2009-11-04`: this is a development snapshot that is now over 3 years old! At least upgrade to a release - 24.2 is the current one.

Comment: it is now implemented and images work fine in org-mode 9.6.1. see documentation about images.

Answer (score 1):

It may be considered heresy, but what about [OneNote](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_OneNote)? It's WYSIWYG and freeform.